# Merge two branch revisions using Subversion

Tags: svn

I'd like to merge all the changes that took place between rev 10 & the HEAD rev on http://url-of-branch-a and apply them to http://url-of-branch-b.

Something like...

```
svn merge -r 10:HEAD http://url-of-branch-a
```

Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax?

I am running the SVN client from the unix command line. The SVN client version is 1.4

EDIT: Yes, my specific solution was...

1. change directory to the location of my working copy that wants to receive the changes (branch-b)
2. svn merge -r 10:HEAD http://url-of-branch-a

This merges the changes from 'branch-a' into 'branch-b'

Comment: You also need to know when the branch was taken. You can do this (svn log --stop-on-copy .) in your branch to get the revision number you branched from.

Comment: @jmc you don't need this anymore since year 2008 when SVN 1.5 was released, AFAIR

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Checkout URL A.
Use SVN merge to merge URL B to your working copy of A.
Commit A.

Or vice versa of course :)

Answer (score 129):

The process is as follows:

1. Establish a working copy of branch B (`svn checkout http://branch-b`)
2. Merge changes from branch A into working copy of B (`svn merge -r 10:HEAD http://branch-a .`)
3. Commit (after resolving conflicts) working copy B to branch b (`svn commit`)

Check the man page (help file) for svn merge semantics. It shows you that svn merge always dumps the results into a working copy.

Check out [the SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html) for all the details.

Comment: Could you also give an idea how to do it using SVN plugin in eclipse ?

Comment: This works for me: svn merge --force --allow-mixed-revisions -r 10:HEAD http://branch-a

Comment: why do we specify revision 10 to HEAD? Why two revision endpoints instead of just one revision to use as a snapshot? which branch does "10 to HEAD" refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly confuse `merge` by trying to do in svn repo, we can not directly merge to svn repo, we can merge to working copy of local machine as follows:

- This working copy should be `destination URL` of merge(i.e. checkout destination).
- merge working copy with `source URL` of merge.
- `commit` to destination.

**Best Practice** : Merge In , Merge Out.