# how to merge / copy the latest revision from a branch to another branch

Tags: svn

suppose I have two branches, A and B. A has the latest change withe new files. 
I want to copy whatever in A into B so that B has all the changes made in A. 
How do I do this?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266338/svn-merge-one-branch-into-another?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprisingly, you should use `svn merge`.  See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

[svn merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html):

> svn merge — Apply the differences between two sources to a working copy path.