# How to synchronize files between 2 svn branches?

Tags: svn, branch

If I have 2 svn branches:

`/branches/dev/myproj` and `/branches/test/myproj`

`myproj` is the project name.
Can I synchronize the modification to `/branches/test/myproj` when I modify the files under `/branches/dev/myproj`

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called "merge"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1266519/1023562