# SVN command to merge head revsion with another head revision

Tags: svn, command-line

SVN folder structure:

```
repo/
    trunk
    trunk-merge
    tags
    branch/
        me/
            sprint-01
```

I need to run a command to merge sprint-01 into trunk-merge, both head revisions.

Now I run the following command for switches:

```
svn switch https://xxxxxxx/xxx/repo/trunk-merge /var/www/project/
```

How do I need to build this command for my merge scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN - merge one branch into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266338/svn-merge-one-branch-into-another)

Answer (score 1):

1. You swich command have wrong format and useless in common
2. After reading SVN Book (or, at least, `svn help merge`), you'll discover: in order to merge any two nodes you have to:

   - have clean Working Copy of destination (into which you'll merge): `svn co https://xxxxxxx/xxx/repo/trunk-merge && cd trunk-merge` or you can switch unused WC of another tree of repository to trunk-merge `cd $SOMEPATH && svn switch ^/trunk-merge`
   - know URL of source node (from which you'll get changes)

and use 1-st form of merge ("complete merge")

```
cd $TRUNK-MERGE
svn merge ^/branch/me/sprint-01
```

---

### Addition

Ok, step-by-step show with toy-repo (sorry for partially Russian locale, I'm too lazy to switch it)

## Initial conditions

Log (full) of repo with trunk and work-in branch

```
WC>svn log -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2016-01-16 16:57:50 +0500 (Сб, 16 янв 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/sprint01/a.txt

Added non-conflicting change to a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2016-01-16 16:56:16 +0500 (Сб, 16 янв 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/sprint01/Sub
   A /branches/sprint01/Sub/c.txt
   A /branches/sprint01/b.txt

Added  b.txt, dir Sub and file Sub/c.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2016-01-16 16:53:32 +0500 (Сб, 16 янв 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/sprint01 (from /trunk:2)

Create branch sprint01 from trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2016-01-16 16:51:12 +0500 (Сб, 16 янв 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/a.txt

Commit a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2016-01-16 16:48:47 +0500 (Сб, 16 янв 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk

Imported folder structure
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

State of trunk

```
>svn ls -v "^/trunk"
      2 Badger                янв 16 16:51 ./
      2 Badger             18 янв 16 16:51 a.txt
```

State of branch

```
>svn ls -v -R "^/branches/sprint01"
      5 Badger                янв 16 16:57 ./
      4 Badger                янв 16 16:56 Sub/
      4 Badger             18 янв 16 16:56 Sub/c.txt
      5 Badger             36 янв 16 16:57 a.txt
      4 Badger             18 янв 16 16:56 b.txt
```

## Merging attempt

I'll try to merge branch's changes (from the point of divergence to the end) **to** trunk, note current directory for merging

```
WC\trunk>svn merge "^/branches/sprint01" .
--- Merging r3 through r5 into '.':
U    a.txt
A    b.txt
A    Sub
A    Sub\c.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r3 through r5 into '.':
 U   .
```

No errors, all added and updated

```
WC\trunk>svn st
 M      .
A  +    Sub
M       a.txt
A  +    b.txt
```

## Trunk after committing mergeset

```
>svn ls -v -R "^/trunk"
      6 Badger                янв 16 17:26 ./
      6 Badger                янв 16 17:26 Sub/
      4 Badger             18 янв 16 16:56 Sub/c.txt
      6 Badger             36 янв 16 17:26 a.txt
      6 Badger             18 янв 16 17:26 b.txt
```

Comment: Sorry none of both work, and they just don't offer any out put. I had to cancel both. (SVN Repositories are in the same machine)
[machine].user:project > svn merge https://xxxx/xxx/xxx/branch/me/sprint-01
[machine].user:project > svn merge ^/branch/me/sprint-01

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean with "show diff between URLs"? Ok, I write again the commands being more specific [machine].user:project > svn merge https:// basename/somefolder/repo_svn/branch/me/sprint-01
[machine].user:project > svn merge ^/branch/me/sprint-01 

And in addition, what doest it mean the "^" before the path?

Comment: I copied all the commands you wrote above, and all of them works but still the same trying to merge, it just gets stuck without displaying nothing and I have to stop it. Appreciating your help