# Where did all the intermediate revisions go when I merged two branches?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I recently merged *branch X* into *branch Y*. I expected the revision history from *branch X* to be merged somehow into the revision history of *branch Y*. Instead all I see is the revision history for *branch Y* with one commit merging in all of the changes from *branch X*. I intend to delete *branch X* in order to tidy up redundant branches.

To do the merge I checked out *branch Y*, then did an `svn merge` with *branch X*, then committed the changes back to *branch Y* (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266338/svn-merge-one-branch-into-another/1266357#1266357)).

Is the revision history for *branch X* now lost? Or is it still accessible somehow? And if so then how?

Comment: Make sure to use the latest SVN 1.9 client.

Answer (score 2):

When you merge a range of history from a branch a single commit will be created on the target branch. See [basic merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) in svn book for more info. You can see the merged commits in the history using the `-g` option to [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.logblame).

Here is an example log from the Trac project. r14725 was a merge of r14724.

```
$svn log -g -r 14724:14725
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r14725 | jomae | 2016-04-15 09:48:06 -0700 (Fri, 15 Apr 2016) | 2 lines

1.2dev: merge [14724] from 1.0-stable (fix for #12364)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r14724 | jomae | 2016-04-15 09:43:24 -0700 (Fri, 15 Apr 2016) | 2 lines
Merged via: r14725

1.0.11dev: make labels in batch-modify form focusable to the control (closes #12364)
```