# Do you lose branch versions after merging it back into the trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

Let's assume I have a SVN repo and decide to make a branch from the trunk. I do development on this branch and make several commits to this branch. Because of this, I have the ability to go back to different versions of my branch.

But now let's assume that I merge this branch back into the trunk. Have I now lost all information regarding those branch versions?

For example, if I realized that I introduced a new bug into the system and wanted to go back to an older version of my branch, can I somehow do this?

Answer (score 0):

After merging a branch to the trunk you can view the history of the commits merged to trunk using the `-g` option to `svn log`. I wrote about that in an answer to [Where did all the intermediate revisions go when I merged two branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774295/121694).

Even after deleting a branch you can still checkout that branch using a peg revision or the `-r` option to `svn update` or `svn checkout`. In the same way, you can checkout or update to a revision of the trunk or any other branch. See [Fetching older repository snapshots](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.snapshots) in the SVN book for more details, or read about the `-r` argument in the svn help: `svn help checkout` and `svn help update`.