# SVN - online Merge revisions from branch A into another branch B without checking-out to local system?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I'd like to merge all the changes that took place between rev 10 & the HEAD rev on http://url-of-branch-a and apply them to http://url-of-branch-b, but I don't want to checkout branch-b.

Something like...

```
svn merge -r 10:HEAD http://url-of-branch-a http://url-of-branch-b
```

Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax?

I am using Tortoise-SVN on windows 7.

> I have seen solutions given on
>   [SVN - merge one branch into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266338/svn-merge-one-branch-into-another)
>   But in those  need to
>
> - check-out branch b
> - merge a to b
> - commit changes in branch b

Answer (score 0):

Merge **always** happens in Working Copy. Period

Comment: May I know why so? Because i have done online merge on Perforce. So I guess svn may also have the same option.